# why some icon doesn't appear correctly when we include the css folder in nodejs?

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an interface using Bootstrap and CSS,but when I run this page without including the project in nodejs program the page appears very well but when I include the bootstrap folder in nodejs program,some icons didn't appear such as the logout icon and login icon(I got a recatngle in place of the suitable icon).Does any one know what is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Are you using font awsome for the icons? if so have you included those in you code ie,the following code into the head section of your site's HTML.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">?
```

Comment: I include only this:bootstrap.min.css

Comment: i'm assuming you are trying to use font awesome for the icons, yes? what is you code html that should show the icon/s?

Comment: the glyphicon of login and logout doesn't appear.

Comment: :I use <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">

Answer (score 0):

I added this two tag to the header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```